# Python: Reading texts only after specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

I am having a pdf of an email communication as shown below

```
Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
To: Jonathan Small <j.small@xyz.com>

FYI...

From: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>
To: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Approval Required for Travel

Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required
```

Objective: I want to read the body of the email i.e. `Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required`.

My Approach So far:

I am using regex. But first the entire pdf is converted into text. Post that I am converting them into list.

```
txt = pdf_to_text(email) # let's assume there is a function that does the conversion jobs. 
txt = txt.split('\n')
pat = re.compile(r'appro.*\,re.I)
extract_txt = [f for f in txt if pat.search(f)]
```

The above code is generating a list as follows:

```
['Approval', 'Approve','approval']
```

**What I want is run the regex only on the mail body and not the subject part.**

Few Assumptions:

1. Mail body shall contain the word 'Approve'
2. Subject line may or may not contain the word 'Approve'

How can I tackle this issue? One way to ensure that I am only picking up the mail content is to ensure to apply regex after the `subject line`. 
Any clue?

P.S. I can't use any python email library like IMAPlib.

Comment: Usually emails have specific attributes for header, body etc. Check it, maybe it helps you

Comment: whats your requirement to print the body of the mail? also your to mail samples are not in the same format. one has a date and subject line the other doesnt

Comment: Python has an [email parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html) built into the standard library. Have you tried using that?

Comment: @Tomalak: I need to check the same.

Comment: As long as you can split the input into individual message text blocks in the standard MIME format (`Header: Value\r\nHeader: Value\r\n\r\nBody"`) this module will give you easy access to the various properties of the message, much easier than trying to do it with regex at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have converted this all to lines of texts and assuming the mail format is consistent like From field is start of a new email and end of the body of last mail and that Subject field is the last header of a mail and start of the body. You can just set a flag to True when you see subject line indicating next lines are the body. Then set that flag when you see the From line indicating the body has ended.

Then when the flag is true and you are in the body you can do what ever you like. In the sample code below i am just collecting all the lines from the body of the mail (excluding blank lines) into a list. I can then do what ever i like with that list for example check it for lines which contain approve.

```
import re

emails = """
From: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
To: Jonathan Small <j.small@xyz.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Stuff

FYI...

From: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>
To: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Approval Required for Travel

Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required

From: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
To: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Approval Required for Travel

ok thanks Keven, will talk to Ruth

"""
body = False
email_bodys = []
for line in emails.splitlines():
    if not line:
        continue
    if line.startswith("From: "):
        body = False
    if body:
        email_bodys.append(line)
    if line.startswith("Subject: "):
        body = True
print("email bodys detected in the text are:\n\t" + "\n\t".join(email_bodys))

print("text in body which contain approve:")
for email_body in email_bodys:
    if re.findall(r'approve', email_body, re.I):
        print("\t" + email_body)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
email bodys detected in the text are:
    FYI...
    Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required
    ok thanks Keven, will talk to Ruth
text in body which contain approve:
    Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required
```

Comment: I will add this is a simple example and doesnt cater for edge cases like the line of the body starting with one of the key phrases like `From: ` or `Subject: `

Comment: Thank Chris. I am also working in this same line, however I liked the `body` logic. Let me try the `email` part as well.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't matter whether `Approve` / `Approved` / `Approval` is in the subject or body of the email you can do this:

```
import re

text = '''From: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
To: Jonathan Small <j.small@xyz.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Stuff

FYI...

From: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>
To: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Approval Required for Travel

Can't Approve as Ruth's approval is required

From: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>
To: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>
Date: 21 Sep 2019
Subject: Approval Required for Travel

ok thanks Keven, will talk to Ruth
'''

email_regex = re.compile(
    r'(From:(?:(?!From:).)+)',
    re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE
)
approval_regex = re.compile(
    r'approv(?:e|ed|al)',
    re.IGNORECASE
)
approved_emails = [
   email for email in email_regex.findall(text)
   if approval_regex.search(email)
]
print(approved_emails)

# output
[
   "From: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>\nTo: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>\nDate: 21 Sep 2019\nSubject: Approval Required for Travel\n\nCan't Approve as Ruth's approval is required\n\n",
   'From: Jerrmy Bret <jeremy.brett@mnop.com>\nTo: Keven Koster <keve.koster@mnop.com>\nDate: 21 Sep 2019\nSubject: Approval Required for Travel\n\nok thanks Keven, will talk to Ruth\n'
]
```

If it matters then you can change the `approval_regex` to be like this:

```
approval_regex = re.compile(
    r'Subject:.+\n.*approv(?:e|ed|al)',
    re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE
)
```